# Intel UHD 630 only display resolution max 1024x768

Tags: graphics, display, display-resolution, intel

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04 here and I can't set the resolution to FULL HD.

I used the command

```
inxi -Fxz
```

[image]

Graphics:

- Device-1: Intel 8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
  vendor: ASRock driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0
- Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.4 driver: i915 resolution: 1024×768~60Hz
- OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel UHD Graphics 630 (Coffeelake 3x8 GT2)
  v: 4.5 Mesa 19.2.0-devel (git-84816d1 2019-05-13 disco-oibaf-ppa)
- direct render: Yes

Someone can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: How is it connected to the monitor? VGA, HDMI, DVI, DP,...? What's the native resolution of that monitor?

Comment: Hello! VGA and native resolution is 1980x1080

Comment: That would be 1920x1080 and VGA is the problem. HDMI, DVI or DP (digital connections) always work fine. Analog is a hit and miss. You may need to use something like xrandr to enable the proper resolution.

Comment: Hello, Gabriela! Thanks for you answer! I used xrandr to set full HD here
Have nice day and thanks again!

Comment: Update: but when i restated the server the resolution returned =\
but i will try another ways here
thanks again!